What size outdoor breaker box do I need?
I'm running the electric cable for a new heat pump install. On the wall where the unit will be placed I'm going to put the subpanel breaker, but I'm wondering what the best choice is. I've run a 6 AWG cable to the wall connected to a 50A breaker in the main panel. The heat pump calls for MOP of 45 and MCA of 35. I bought a 70-Amp 2-Spaces 4-Circuit outdoor "main lug load center". I'm not planning on connecting anything myself, but want to have the box installed so the electrician only has to connect everything. Is this the right box? The choice basically boiled down to what was readily available.
Update:
I didn't get the 6AWG cable in the wall before putting the side up. As a result I've had to come down the wall from the attic using a 1 in. conduit. If it's a disconnect I need instead of a breaker, what's the best way to wire into the disconnect box? Using one of the punch outs on the side of the box?


Why a subpanel?  The purpose of the 120V socket rule is that HVAC repair requires use of a vacuum pump, and those are presumed to come with 25' cords.  ANY outdoor receptacle will suffice - in fact one at the HVAC unit is a bad idea, because it will only get used every 15 years and the GFCI will have failed due to weather. So it won't even work.  FAR better to find an ideal location *within 25' for a socket you'll find generally useful - for lawn tools, BBQ, holiday lighting, bouncy castles, or whatever.

Disconnect, subpanel, general junction box, whatever - all (provided they are made of metal) have plenty of knockouts and you mount it so that the conduit fits into one of them. Important: What is the rating/type of this cable? If this is NM-B rated for dry locations only then it can't be outside in conduit.

Yes. Use one of the knockouts on the side of the box with an LB for the conduit. Weatherproof enclosures for outdoors are not meant to be penetrated on the top of the enclosure unless they are a service meter enclosure designed for a special hub on top. See the answer below regarding the NM-B cable used outdoors. You would have to pull THWN rated wire from the last J-box indoors to the disconnect if you have to pass inspection.

I have the wire going uncut from the main panel on the back of the house up through the attic and down the conduit where you see it in the photo.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I don't have the cable package anymore. Would there be a way to tell by just by looking at the cable what rating/type it is? I don't see anything printed on the cable insulation/jacket. Can you tell from the photo what the rating is?

There is usually, but not always, printing on the cable every few feet. Can't tell from the picture.

The cable jacket is (pretty universally) marked every 2 feet. That marking may be hard to see, as it might only be molded into the jacket rather than printed with contrasting ink, but it will be there.

You don't normally need a subpanel for a heat pump. In fact, that can be a problem because of the open space required in front of any subpanel (30" wide x 36" deep), and outside you typically have (a) the heat pump itself close to the wall and (b) trees/shrubs/etc.
What you do need is a disconnect, but that is normally done with a < $20 box designed for just that purpose, such as this GE from Home Depot:

The other reason for a subpanel is if you need multiple circuits. You do need a 20A receptacle circuit within 25 feet of the heat pump. You may already have such a receptacle. If not, you can add one with a 20A breaker connected to 12 AWG wire. You probably can't actually use that "2 space/4 circuit" to have a 35A/40A/45A double-breaker for the heat pump plus 20A single-breaker for the receptacle because breakers larger than 30A aren't generally available in half-size form factor. So if you actually wanted to use a subpanel for that reason you would need a larger subpanel.
Note that in the case of both the disconnect and the receptacle, you can't actually use ordinary NM-B cable ("Romex") outside as that is not outdoor rated. Most places will allow you to feed NM-B cable directly into the back of a junction box such that no cable is directly exposed to the outdoors.
6 AWG NM-B is good for up to 55A. You need to downsize the breaker to somewhere between 35A and 45A.

I agree that the NM-B cable cannot be used outdoors. Disconnects require the same working space in front of them as panels. He should be able to use a 4 space panel with a 2 pole breaker for the hot tub and a single breaker for the receptacle.

Disconnects require the same working space in front of them as panels. - Citation needed. And yes, a 4-space panel will work, but OP listed a 2-space/4 "circuit" which won't.

NEC 110.26(A) does apply to disconnects, as it defines the required working space around electrical equipment, including disconnecting means, like circuit breakers and disconnect switches, ensuring proper access for maintenance and operation; essentially, any electrical equipment that needs working space around it falls under this section. Disconnecting means for HVAC equipment that is also part of service equipment, switchboards, switchgears, panelboards, or motor control centers, must comply with section 110.26(A). I agree with your comment regarding the OPs post.

Interesting. I have found quite a debate about this out on the web. And a specific reference https://www.ncosfm.gov/electrical/11026-working-space-and-clearances/open for NC where they specifically say outdoor HVAC equipment including disconnect doesn't have the 110.26(A) requirement. And some of the debate about it seemed to say "until NEC 2023 there was room for leniency on disconnects". And anecdotally (which doesn't count for much), I see plenty of HVAC disconnects mounted in locations that absolutely don't have 110.26(A) space in front of them.

Normally, HVAC disconnects are mounted outdoors or on the outside of the equipment with plenty of room like on a roof or side of a house. Motor disconnects in an MCC however can have many other pieces of equipment mounted nearby. And I agree, the code is violated all the time. The other thing for people to watch out for is the equipment doors on hinged panels must be able to open at least 90 degrees. This can especially become an issue with large disconnects with bump outs on the doors mounted near an adjacent wall.

It appears NC has made an exception for standard disconnects on HVAC equipment. "The State Electrical Division does not consider heat pumps, air handlers, duct heaters, their respective disconnecting means, or similar HVAC accessory devices and equipment as “likely to require examination, adjustment, servicing, or maintenance while energized”. " So, if the State Inspector says it's OK then you get a pass.
